# Custom segmentation and override segmentation rules in spacy

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3, text-segmentation

I want to split into sentences a large corpus (.txt) with a **custom rule** i.e. {SENT} using Spacy 3.1.

My main issue is that I want to "disable" the segmentation from the pretrained spacy models with spacy i.e. `en_core_web_lg` but keep all the other components (tokenisation, syntactic parser, ner etc.). I am always using the large models (I read that the segmentation may behave differently based on the model used).

Is there a way to **override** the existing rules and only using {SENT} as a delimiter while maintaining the rest of the pipe ?
If I add the custom segmentation to the pipe before parser : `nlp.add_pipe(set_custom_segmentation, before='parser')`, will the parser resplit the sentences based on the delimiters provided from the models ?

I already tried the following with no luck :

```
@Language.component("segm")
def set_custom_segmentation(doc):
    for token in doc[:-1]:
        if token.text == '{SENT}':
            doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = False
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe('segm', before='parser')
```

Solutions I've tried until now but didn't work :

1. provide to spacy a list of "sentences" with `split("{SENT}")` and `re.split("{SENT}")`
2. The answer proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54529875/spacy-custom-sentence-spliting)

Answer (score 1):

You have to also set `token.is_sent_start = False` for the remaining tokens if you don't want the parser to potentially add additional sentence boundaries.

Comment: I set it to False but I still have some sentences with only punctuation marks : 
{
... 
whereas in the initial segmentated file you would never find for instance {SENT}...{SENT}

Comment: It's hard to know without a concrete example to look at. If you have a minimal example where the parser isn't respecting the `is_sent_start` values, please submit a bug report in the issue tracker. (Also note that `{SENT}` isn't a single token by default in many languages, in case that is a factor.)

Comment: For instance this sentance should be considered as one, whereas I get 8 : 
1) —
2) Quel âge as
3) -tu?
4) demanda Angel.
5) — Je ne sais pas, —
6) Sais
7) tu faire la soupe ?
8) {SENT}L'homme (etc. etc. the phrase continues until the next {SENT})